# getting xml node as comma delimited list via select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Xml is stored in a varchar column.

One of the nodes is like

```
<PreviousItem>
<string>501</string>
<string>502</string>
<string>505</string>
</PreviousItem>
```

I need to get this nodes elements as `comma delimited list (having issue with this part only)` along with other items in this xml and the table.

```
SELECT
     nId, cDescription, 
    ,CAST(cSettings AS XML).value('data(/clsSettings/PreviousItem)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PreviousItem
    ,CAST(cSettings AS XML).value('data(/clsSettings/RegistrationType)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS RegistrationType
FROM tblX
```

The above is giving me PreviousItem as `501502505`.

i have tried following but i am getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'` in `CAST(cSettings AS XML)`

```
( SELECT    
            STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + Prods.Prod.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                    FROM    CAST(cSettings AS XML).nodes('/clsSettings/PreviousItem') AS Prods ( Prod )
                    FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
        ) prods
```

Comment: Is there a reason the XML is stored in varchar?  As a general rule, it is recommended you use the right [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh403385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the job.  This has several benefits including: it is harder to enter invalid data and it is easier to work with (for example, there would be no need to cast the column each time).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: I don't have any control over the DB, I got it like this so don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @tblX TABLE (cID int identity, cSettings xml);
INSERT @tblX (cSettings)
VALUES 
('<PreviousItem>
<string>501</string>
<string>502</string>
<string>505</string>
</PreviousItem>'),
('<PreviousItem>
<string>4433</string>
<string>5577</string>
</PreviousItem>');

-- Solution
SELECT 
  cID,
  PreviousItem = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ',' + x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
      FROM @tblX t
      CROSS APPLY cSettings.nodes('/PreviousItem/string') x(x)
      WHERE t.cID = tx.cId
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
  )
FROM @tblX tx;
```

Based on your sample data you have a RegistrationType that lives in your XML that you need to get... Here's a tweaked version of my first solution.

```
-- Updated Sample Data with RegistrationType
DECLARE @tblX TABLE (cID int identity, cSettings xml);
INSERT @tblX (cSettings)
VALUES 
('<PreviousItem>
<string>501</string>
<string>502</string>
<string>505</string>
</PreviousItem>
<RegistrationType>Type A</RegistrationType>
'),
('<PreviousItem>
<string>4433</string>
<string>5577</string>
</PreviousItem>
<RegistrationType>Type B</RegistrationType>
');

-- Solution which includes RegistrationType
SELECT 
  cID,
  PreviousItem = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ',' + x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
      FROM @tblX t
      CROSS APPLY cSettings.nodes('/PreviousItem/string') x(x)
      WHERE t.cID = tx.cId
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
  ),    
  RegistrationType = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ',' + x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
      FROM @tblX t
      CROSS APPLY cSettings.nodes('RegistrationType') x(x)
      WHERE t.cID = tx.cId
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
  )
FROM @tblX tx;
```

For a more accurate solution please include some DDL and consumable sample data and I can modify my solution accordingly.

Update: because your XML data is stored as text you would need to tweak my original solution like so:

```
-- Updated Sample Data with RegistrationType
DECLARE @tblX TABLE (cID int identity, cSettings varchar(max));
INSERT @tblX (cSettings)
VALUES 
('<PreviousItem>
<string>501</string>
<string>502</string>
<string>505</string>
</PreviousItem>
<RegistrationType>Type A</RegistrationType>
'),
('<PreviousItem>
<string>4433</string>
<string>5577</string>
</PreviousItem>
<RegistrationType>Type B</RegistrationType>
');

-- Solution which includes RegistrationType
SELECT 
  cID,
  PreviousItem = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ',' + x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
      FROM @tblX t
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CAST(cSettings AS xml))) xx(xx)
      CROSS APPLY xx.xx.nodes('/PreviousItem/string') x(x)
      WHERE t.cID = tx.cId
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
  ),
  RegistrationType = STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT ',' + x.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(500)')
      FROM @tblX t
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CAST(cSettings AS xml))) xx(xx)
      CROSS APPLY xx.xx.nodes('RegistrationType') x(x)
      WHERE t.cID = tx.cId
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
  )
FROM @tblX tx;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My xml is residing inside a varchar field and not xml. Your example is using .node which only works for the xml types.

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with your data being stored as varchar.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dealing with text and not XML you could handle this much more efficiently using some basic T-SQL and [PatExclude8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/) like so:

```
-- Updated Sample Data with RegistrationType
DECLARE @tblX TABLE (cID int identity, cSettings varchar(max));
INSERT @tblX (cSettings)
VALUES 
('<PreviousItem>
<string>501</string>
<string>502</string>
<string>505</string>
</PreviousItem>
<RegistrationType>Type A</RegistrationType>
'),
('<PreviousItem>
<string>4433</string>
<string>5577</string>
</PreviousItem>
<RegistrationType>Type B</RegistrationType>
');

-- Solution using PatExclude8K
SELECT
  cID, 
  PreviousItem     = SUBSTRING(NewString,1, LEN(NewString)-1),
  RegistrationType = SUBSTRING
  (
    cSettings,
    CHARINDEX('<RegistrationType>', cSettings)+18,
    CHARINDEX('</RegistrationType>', cSettings) - 
      (CHARINDEX('<RegistrationType>', cSettings)+18)
  )
FROM @tblX o
CROSS APPLY dbo.PatExclude8K(REPLACE(cSettings,'</string>',','), '[^0-9,]');
```